# Gathering counters and metrics of individual hadoop jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, metrics

I'm looking for a way of gathering all the counters and metrics of individual hadoop jobs in an event-driven way to store all this data within elasticsearch for later troubleshooting and analysis.

Currently I found few methods which could have seemed to fit the requirements:

1. Using metric exporters, especially, [ContainerMetrics](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/containermanager/monitor/ContainerMetrics.java) that allows to obtain per-container memory and cpu usage and [MRAppMetrics](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/metrics/MRAppMetrics.java), but that one *aggregates* all the metrics for all the jobs.
2. Polling MR History Server with its [REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html) that is pretty straightforward, but requires a lot of HTTP calls to gather all the counters for jobs, tasks and their attempts.
3. Plugging an additional custom [EventHandler](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/event/EventHandler.java) into [MRAppMaster](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/MRAppMaster.java)'s event [dispatcher](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/MRAppMaster.java#L194), but [MRAppMaster](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/MRAppMaster.java) does not have corresponding mechanisms to register custom event handlers.
4. Using black magic of javaagents (java instrumentation api), bytecode modifications and aop-like functionality to intercept all the executions of [EventHandler#handle(T)](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/event/EventHandler.java#L34) method. That way should be able to solve all the requirements, but needs additional configuration of MR-jobs, javaagent development and registration and generally seems to be pretty complex.

So, I'd like to ask whether there are any more simple ways to collect metrics and counters of individual hadoop jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can feed your metrics to whatever recipient actually: implement your own [MetricsSink](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsSink.html) and configure hadoop to use it.

Or you can use a MetricsSink already bundled with Hadoop distro, like [GraphiteSink](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/sink/GraphiteSink.html) and get your metrics in Graphite.

Note that some counters are not available until the job has finished (successfully or not).

Also, option 2 is also a risk to get HistoryServer into trouble (when you poll for a job with a jillion of mappers, it might OOM).

Comment: Exporting with metric sinks is pretty easy, but how to create and register new metric sources to gather, for example, custom job counters?

Comment: Implementing a MetricsSource is straightforward as well, http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/package-summary.html

Comment: How to feed this newly implemented MetricsSource with custom job counters? Lets take as an example MRAppMetrics. Instances of this class are used directly within [MRAppMaster](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/MRAppMaster.java#L190), JobImpl, MapTaskImpl, ReduceTaskImpl, etc. directly. So it seems that its hardly possible to plug custom metric source into the framework to gather job counters

Comment: There is a bit of confusion. Counters and metrics are not the same: metrics pertain to the system and are of interest to 'administrators', counters pertain to jobs and are of interest to job developers. MetricsSink is, well, for metrics. And it is indeed hardly possible to plug metrics source to gather counters. Custom counters for tasks can be exported from your job (loggers, directly pushing updates to graphite, other options that I just can't think of); the ones pertaining to the job can be polled from application master or from RM.

Comment: ... but boundaries between metrics and counters are a little bit blurred. For example, ContainerMetrics gathers per-container metrics, which are also exposed as job counters, MRAppMetrics receives counters and exposes these ones as metrics.